# Paragraph spacing within minibox

Tags: paragraphs, minipage

I have tried all kinds of gimmicks, but I am stuck trying to reduce the double-spacing within the minibox to single space. (Obviously, I want to keep the global \onehalfspacing option.) This sounds trivial (and it probably is), but changing \parskip and \linespread seems to only to work for minipage --- I want to change this in a minibox environment --- what am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}  % tables smaller spacing
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}

\usepackage{minibox}   % minipage without specific width

\begin{document}
\section{Immune System}

\newcommand{\belongs}[2] {  % \belongs
\noindent
\[
\minibox{#1}
\left \{
\minibox{#2}
\right .
\]
}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\belongs{antigen\\presenting\\cells}{
Macrophages \\
Dendritic cells \\
B cells}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\belongs{humoral\\response}{B cells}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\belongs{cell-mediated\\immunity}{
phagocytes \\
killer T cells \\
release of cytokines}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`minibox` is just a one column `tabular` so you can shrink it vertically with `\arraystretch` as it has been stretched already by the `\onehalfspacing`
Also, don't leave a space before the `%` at end of line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}  % tables smaller spacing
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}

\usepackage{minibox}   % minipage without specific width

\begin{document}
\section{Immune System}

\newcommand{\belongs}[2] {% \belongs
\noindent
\[\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.7}  
\minibox{#1}
\left \{
\minibox{#2}
\right .
\]%
}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\belongs{antigen\\presenting\\cells}{
Macrophages \\
Dendritic cells \\
B cells}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\belongs{humoral\\response}{B cells}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\belongs{cell-mediated\\immunity}{
phagocytes \\
killer T cells \\
release of cytokines}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah.  My bad.  The mind fills in the gaps.  Erroneously in this case.  I'll delete my comment.